# pip install succeeded, but setup install failed

Tags: pip, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I used `pip install -r pip_list.txt` successfully.

```py
# setup.py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='test',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['test'],
    install_requires=[
      ...  # Same as pip_list.txt
    ],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        test=test:cli
    ''',
)
```

run `python setup.py install` failed.
`error: idna 3.1 is installed but idna<3,>=2.5 is required by {'requests'}`

pip.conf

```
[global] 
index_url = https://.../prod/+simple/ 
[search] 
index = https://.../prod/
```

setup.cfg

```
[easy_install]
index_url = https://.../prod/+simple/
```

**I did not find the [search] option in setup.cfg**.Is the above error related to this?

Comment: Calling `python setup.py install` or `python setup.py develop` directly is not recommended. It is much better to call `python -m pip install .` or `python -m pip install --editable .`. _setuptools_ does not want to be an "installer" anymore and is not trying to improve on this front anymore. What you are seeing, looks like it could be the lack of an actual dependency resolver in setuptools. setuptools does not really try to find a full, valid combination of dependencies and just installs the dependencies one after the other without checking if they are compatible with each other.

Comment: Because click_plugin needs to use setuptools.https://pypi.org/project/click-plugins/

Comment: Yes, this does not change that setuptools is still the build back-end. It only changes the build front-end from _setuptools_ to _pip_, which is a good thing, and you should not lose any functionality. Give it a try.